# Send datatable data to mysql database C# Form

Tags: c#, mysql, datatable

**file a.csv**
aaa,bbb,,ddd
aba,bab,,dcd

**file b.txt**
bbb,ccc
bab,cbc

**matched**
aaa,bbb,*ccc*,ddd
aba,bab,*cbc*,dcd

Hi all, by referring to text above I have a task involving reading from a csv file with comma delimited and match a column with a text file and save the matched data in a datatable. I have a class that execute all the matching part. But I haven't found a solution to insert all the datatable data into mysql database. I tried to query the datatable into the database but non has worked out. Thank you.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: So, is any of the "csv and match to text" part of your question relevant or is your problem simply "I want to upload the contents of a datatable to MySQL" ?

Comment: @Matthias I tried to make a query but cannot find a way to insert the data of each column from datatable into each column in database

Comment: @CaiusJard My apologies. yeah I think it simply just that. I need to insert the matched data from datatable to mysql.

Comment: Are the datatable column names the same the database column names?

Comment: @CaiusJard Yes. its all the same.

Comment: @CaiusJard I want to pass the datatable value to the query.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need to write the query.. It should just work like:

```
var dataSet = new DataSet();
dataSet.Tables.Add(YOUR_DATA_TABLE);

using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    var adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter ();
    adapter.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM YOUR_DB_TABLE", connection);
    var builder = new MySqlCommandBuilder(adapter);

    
    adapter.InsertCommand = builder.GetInsertCommand();
    adapter.Update(dataSet); //i know it says "update, but it runs INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE query depending on the RowState
}
```

The rows in your datatable must have a RowState of Added, which they will have if they have been added via `datatable.Rows.Add(...)` and you have not called AcceptChanges on the table. If your rows are not in stated Added, you'll have to call SetAdded on each one that isn't

Comment: Thank you! I'll try and get back soon.